# Strategy to migrate data from Oracle Database to MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, oracle, database-migration, data-modeling

I have an existing Oracle database with production data. I am planning to move to MongoDB, so I want to migrate my existing data in Oracle database to MongoDB. The Data Model of data stored in Oracle database and MongoDB will be different.

I am planning to get all the data from Oracle database as json using https://blogs.oracle.com/jsondb/generating-json-data. Once I will have the json file with all the data I will import that in the MongoDB. In case the data extracted from Oracle database is not per my required I will create a utility to convert the data to multiple json file for each collection.

I need to some suggestions if there are better ways to this and is my solution right approach for the problem?

Comment: If you have small data, that is fine IMHO. No need to write some code. You didn't tag any languages, otherwise MongoDb language drivers already have support for conversion to json during streaming of data.

Comment: Another way to get data out of Oracle in JSON format is to use the SQLcl command line tool. Look for "Set sqlformat json"

Comment: @CetinBasoz My data is a result of some query as I don`t want some crap data to be migrated. I think the size of the query result will be around 1000000.  @AdamvonNieda yes I can use that way as well to fetch the records.

Comment: 1 million is not large but if I were in your shoes, then I would do that as streaming the data from Oracle, shape and save to MongoDb using client drivers. But as I said, that requires a language knowledge and you didn't tag any.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I will surely have a look at language drivers. I hope you are talking about https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/.

Comment: Yes those drivers. Just as a reference, this is some partial code using C# driver: private async Task InsertSampleData(IMongoCollection<Musteri> col)
{
 var data = new List<Musteri>();
 data.Add( new Musteri 
  { 
    Firma = "Ugur Yilmaz",
    Telefon = "123456",
    Siparisler = new List<Siparis> { 
      new Siparis { 
        OrderDate=DateTime.Today.AddDays(-3), 
        BillAddress=new Adres { Cadde="1", KapiNo=2, Sehir="Izmir" },
        ShipAddress = new Adres { Cadde="3", KapiNo=4, Sehir="Izmir" },
        ...